# Immediate manipulation of UIView animatable properties during rotation?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, rotation

I am trying to accomplish some complex effects during my UIView rotation, and I'm using the first half/second half method of rotation animations.

However, when my second half starts, I'd like to set some properties on my subviews (alpha, frame) etc, from which to begin animating in the second half. But setting any of these properties of course causes them to be animated. I'd like to say, set the alpha to 0.0, and THEN say, "ok, now animate it to 1.0 throughout the rest of the rotation."

Note that I can't set this property before the whole rotation; I want to affect its immediate value partway through.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: (Wow, care you comment on your drive-by downvote, stranger?)

Answer (score 0):

Implement this function in your UIControllerView :

```
- (void)willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how this plays into the rotation animation? That's not something that I start explicitly.

Comment: try to add this code in the UIViewController : 
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you've quite got the question. I know how to animate in general. But during rotation, the system creates animations for you, and I want to change an instantaneous value in the middle of the rotation.